# code the following word using the sample code logic

Tags: cipher, pattern

**Sample**

apple  =  btqreqemf

mango  =  ntbreoehp

banana  =  ctbreoebob

**code:**

orange = ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

> ptsrebehf

Code:

> Each coded word takes the form `_t_re_e`, with the spaces and end filled in by the letters of the original word, shifted forward by one in the alphabet.